# Consulta con ajax no se realiza y no me da error

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, ajax

Estoy empezando con ajax. Tengo un input que genera una busqueda con ajax en mi base de datos mysql, pero no me devuelve ningún resultado y la consola no muestra ningun error

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#resultadoBusqueda").html('<p>JQUERY VACIO</p>');
});

function buscar() {
    var textoBusqueda = $("input#busqueda").val();
 
     if (textoBusqueda != "") {
        $.post("buscar.php", {valorBusqueda: textoBusqueda}, function(mensaje) {
            $("#resultadoBusqueda").html(mensaje);
         }); 
     } else { 
        $("#resultadoBusqueda").html('<p>JQUERY VACIO</p>');
        };
};
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<form accept-charset="utf-8" method="POST">
 <input type="text" name="busqueda" id="busqueda" value="" placeholder="" maxlength="30" autocomplete="off" onKeyUp="buscar();" />
</form>
<div id="resultadoBusqueda"></div>
```

**Y este es el código del archivo buscar.php**

```html
<?php
require('../conexion.php');

$consultaBusqueda = $_POST['valorBusqueda'];

$caracteres_malos = array("<", ">", "\"", "'", "/", "<", ">", "'", "/");
$caracteres_buenos = array("& lt;", "& gt;", "& quot;", "& #x27;", "& #x2F;", "& #060;", "& #062;", "& #039;", "& #047;");
$consultaBusqueda = str_replace($caracteres_malos, $caracteres_buenos, $consultaBusqueda);

$mensaje = "";

if (isset($consultaBusqueda)) {

  $consulta = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM respuestos
  WHERE maquina COLLATE UTF8_SPANISH_CI LIKE '%$consultaBusqueda%' 
  OR repuesto COLLATE UTF8_SPANISH_CI LIKE '%$consultaBusqueda%'
  OR CONCAT(maquina,' ',repuesto) COLLATE UTF8_SPANISH_CI LIKE '%$consultaBusqueda%'
  ");

  $filas = mysqli_num_rows($consulta);

  if ($filas === 0) {
    $mensaje = "<p>No hay ninguna maquina y/o repuesto</p>";
  } else {
    echo 'Resultados para <strong>'.$consultaBusqueda.'</strong>';

    while($resultados = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)) {
      $maquina = $resultados['maquina'];
      $repuesto = $resultados['repuesto'];
      $ref = $resultados['ref'];

      $mensaje .= '
      <p>
      <strong>maquina:</strong> ' . $maquina . '<br>
      <strong>repuesto:</strong> ' . $repuesto . '<br>
      <strong>Ref.:</strong> ' . $ref . '<br>
      </p>';

    };
  };
};
echo $mensaje;
?>
```

**Este es el SQL de mi tabla con 1 registro**

```html
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

CREATE TABLE `repuestos` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ref` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `tipo` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `maquina` varchar(400) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `repuesto` varchar(400) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO `repuestos` (`id`, `ref`, `tipo`, `maquina`, `repuesto`) VALUES
(1, 'BM-154D80', 'Sierra', 'Sierra BM-180', 'Cinta 1600 Hueso');

ALTER TABLE `repuestos`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `repuestos`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=2;
COMMIT;
```

**Y aquí el archivo de conexión, este archivo me ha funcionado bien con otra tabla durante un año por lo que no creo que sea el problema**

```html
<?php
function dbConnect (){
  $conn = null;
  $host = 'Localhost';
  $db =  '****';
  $user = '*****';
  $pwd =  '*****';
 try {
     $conn = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$db, $user, $pwd);

 }
 catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo '<p>Error al conectar a la base de datos</p>';
     exit;
 }
 return $conn;
 }

 ?>
```

Comment: El post veo que se dispara con el key up. Podés agregarle al post la funcion fail(jqXHR, textStatus) para loguear a la consola si falla el ajax.

Comment: en el php por las dudas ponele un `exit;` luego del `echo $mensaje;`, como alternativa reemplazar el echo por `exit($mensaje);` o `die($mensaje);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

compañero: Te pongo esto en otra respuesta, porque hay varias razones para que no te funcione.

La primera, la conexión la creas mediante una función en `conexion.php`, pero en `buscar.php` no llamas a esa función para recuperar la conexión, con lo que, en ningún momento, la tienes disponible.

La segunda. Tu tabla se llama **repuestos**, y en la consulta la tienes como **respuestos**, lo que hace que, aunque tuvieras la conexión, la tabla no la vas a localizar.

Pero lo más importante. La conexión la estás efectuando mediante PDO (lo cual es, desde luego, la mejor opción). Sin embargo, en `buscar.php` utilizas la extensión **mysqli** en procedimental, que no funciona con la conexión PDO. Si usas PDO para la conexión, debes usar el objeto creado para las consultas. Te incluyo el código de `buscar.php` aquí (por supuesto, probado y funcionando).

```
<?php
    require('conexion.php');

    $conexion = dbConnect();

    $consultaBusqueda = $_POST['valorBusqueda'];


    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM repuestos
      WHERE maquina COLLATE UTF8_SPANISH_CI LIKE '%$consultaBusqueda%' 
      OR repuesto COLLATE UTF8_SPANISH_CI LIKE '%$consultaBusqueda%'
      OR CONCAT(maquina,' ',repuesto) COLLATE UTF8_SPANISH_CI LIKE '%$consultaBusqueda%';";

    $resultado = $conexion->query($consulta, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $mensaje = '';
    foreach ($resultado as $item) {
      $mensaje .= '
            <p>
            <strong>maquina:</strong> ' . $item["maquina"] . '<br>
            <strong>repuesto:</strong> ' . $item["repuesto"] . '<br>
            <strong>Ref.:</strong> ' . $item["ref"] . '<br>
            </p>';      
    }

    if ($mensaje == '') $mensaje = 'Sin resultados';

    echo $mensaje;

?>
```

También te sugiero que cuando crees una conexión PDO actives la detección de excepciones, lo que es una ayuda en depuración. El script `conexion.php` quedaría así:

```
<?php
    function dbConnect (){
        $conn = null;
        $host = 'localhost';
        $db =   'soe';
        $user = 'root';
        $pwd =  '';
        try {
            $conn = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$db, $user, $pwd);
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }
        catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo '<p>Error al conectar a la base de datos</p>';
            exit;
        }
        return $conn;
    }
?>
```

Observa la línea que he puesto justo debajo de la creación de la conexión.

Las consultas en PDO son más fáciles y "limpias" que en modo procedimental. Te sugiero un par de enlaces que pueden ayudarte: https://eldesvandejose.com/2016/06/16/uso-de-mysql-con-pdo-php-conectar-leer-y-escribir/ y https://eldesvandejose.com/2017/03/26/uso-de-mysql-con-pdo-php-ii-tratamiento-de-excepciones/.

Ten en cuenta que en las pruebas he puesto todos los códigos en el mismo directorio para la prueba. Si los pones en directorios diferentes, tenlo en cuenta al hacer el `require`.

Espero haberte ayudado. Si tienes cualquier duda con esto, aquí estoy.

PD. El nombre del host no lo pongas con mayúscula. En lugar de Localhost, pon localhost. Se que parece que funciona, pero a mí se me han dado casos hace tiempo en que, de repente, sin razón aparente, no funcionaba y era por la capitalización.

Comment: Wow, menuda respuesta, a la altura de @A.Cedano Gracias, funciona a la perfección.

Answer (score 1):

No sé si será un error de transcripción del código, pero en el HTML no tienes ningún contenedor con `id="resultadoBusqueda"`, que es el que usas para alojar el resultado.

Ya que usas jQuery, deja que sea él quien gestione el campo de texto. Sustituye la línea siguiente:

```
<input type="text" name="busqueda" id="busqueda" value="" placeholder="" maxlength="30" autocomplete="off" onKeyUp="buscar();" />
```

por esta:

```
<input type="text" name="busqueda" id="busqueda" value="" placeholder="" maxlength="30" autocomplete="off">
```

A la carga del documento, incorpora la detección del evento. Sustituye:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#resultadoBusqueda").html('<p>JQUERY VACIO</p>');
});
```

por:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#resultadoBusqueda").html('<p>JQUERY VACIO</p>');
    $("#busqueda").on('keyup', function() {
        buscar();
    });
});
```

Aparte de eso, como sugerencia, en la ventana de inspección del navegador abre la pestaña Network. Cada vez que pulses un carácter en el campo de búsqueda, el php tiene que "reaccionar". Por ejemplo, debajo de `$filas = mysqli_num_rows($consulta);` añade `echo "FILAS: ".$filas;` y deberías ver ese resultado en la pestaña Network. Si no te aparece, el PHP no se está ejecutando.

Empieza por ahí, y si no se soluciona me comentas los resultados y seguimos buscando respuestas. Si puedes, añade el SQL de la exportación de tu tabla, y el archivo de conexión, para poder reproducirlo como tú lo tienes, y poder ayudarte mejor.

Un saludo.

Comment: He probado lo que me comentas. En la pestaña network, cada vez que escribo un caracter, reacciona el archivo buscar.php, y pone status 200 ok. He probado a añadir el echo pero no lo muestra en el DOM

Comment: Pues vamos a resolverlo. Pon como te he comentado el archivo de la conexión y el SQL de la exportación de tu tabla, tal como los tienes en tu ordenador, y lo reproduzco. Si tu tabla tiene muchos registros, con que exportes 20 o 30 vale, es sólo para estar seguro de reproducir tus condiciones.

Comment: Actualicé la pregunta con lo que indicas. El modo de conectarme a la DB es correcto, llevo utilizando este metodo casi 1 año